# How to install mongodb in docker by writing commands in Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am getting this error while installing mongodb in docker

> [5/6] RUN apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0:
> #8 0.327 ERROR: unable to select packages:
> #8 0.328   mongodb (no such package):
> #8 0.347     required by: world[mongodb=3.4.4-r0].
> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0]: exit code: 1.

My **Dockerfile** code is given below which is similar to the StackOverflow solution but it is not working for me.

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update
RUN apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0

VOLUME ["/data/db"]
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 27017

CMD [ "mongod" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the repositories, just set the alpine version:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

ENV TERM=linux

RUN apk add --no-cache bash mongodb=3.4.4-r0

RUN mkdir -p /data/db && \
    chown -R mongodb /data/db

VOLUME /data/db
EXPOSE 27017

CMD [ "mongod", "--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I hate to be "that guy", but trying to troubleshoot your solution, it just worked on my machine:

[image: wsl2-ubuntu20.04-screenshot]

Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 (Windows 10) with Docker 20.10.17